# Data loss when converting from QString to QByteArray

Tags: qt4

I'm using QPlainTextEdit as an HTML editor, saving the data through an HTTP post with QNetworkAccessManager.

I experience data loss when using HTML special characters such as & (ampersand)
I'm building a POST request with a QByteArray (as mentioned in the docs).

```
QByteArray postData;
QMapIterator<QString, QString> i(params);
while(i.hasNext()) {
    i.next();
    postData
        .append(i.key().toUtf8())
        .append("=")
        .append(i.value().toUtf8())
        .append("&");
}

postData.remove(postData.length()-1, 1);

//Do request
QNetworkRequest postRequest = QNetworkRequest(res);
oManager.post(postRequest, postData);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not an expert in network programming in Qt, but your code seems like reinventing the wheel. Check out [QUrl](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qurl.html) class - it has setters for query parameters, host, scheme, etc. and can be used directly through QNetworkRequest.

Comment: I've finally found the solution with QUrl and toEncoded() function thanks for your answer.